# Preventing to create non-clustered index in EF Core 3.1 code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, ef-core-3.1, non-clustered-index

In EF Core, by default, it creates a non-clustered index for a foreign key for code-first approach.

I want to prevent creating non-clustered index on the foreign key in the EF Core 3.1.

In Entity Framework "classic" (not Core), I could to do it like remove the `ForeignKeyIndexConvention` convention like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    .....
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ForeignKeyIndexConvention>();
}
```

But, I can't do this in EF Core, it doesn't run the code.

What is the best approach to do it?